# How to add secrets to existing path in vault using terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-modules

I'm new and would appreciate advice on managing secrets in a terraform with vault. We use a modular code structure.

```
./project
├──── dev
│      │
│      ├── local.tf
│      ├── main.tf
│      ├── provider.tf
│      └── terraform.tf
│
├──── qa
│      │
│      ├── local.tf
│      ├── main.tf
│      ├── provider.tf 
│      └── terraform.tf
│
├──── modules
│        │   
│        ├── iam
│        │    │
│        │    ├── main.tf
│        │    ├── variables.tf
│        │    └── outputs.tf
│        │
│        │
│        ├── cert
│        │    │
│        │    ├── main.tf
│        │    ├── variables.tf
│        │    └── outputs.tf
│        └──  ...
└── ...
```

Consider a scenario where a specific module is responsible for storing secrets in a vault:

```
variable vault_path {
  default = "/path/to/secret"
}
```

```
resource "vault_generic_secret" "secret" {
  path = var.vault_path
  data_json = json_encode({
     "SECRET1": "value",
     "SECRET2": "value"
  })
}
```

After some time, I will need to save secrets in another module with the same path. Therefore, I will first need to fetch the secrets, merge them with the existing ones, and then save them.

```
variable vault_path {
  default = "/path/to/secret"
}
```

```
data "vault_generic_secret" "data_secret" {
  path = var.vault_path
}

resource "vault_generic_secret" "secret" {
  path = var.vault_path
  data_json = json_encode(
    merge(
      data.vault_generic_secret.data_secret.data,
      {
        "SECRET3": "value",
        "SECRET4": "value"
      }
    )
  )
}
```

I don't want to repeat the same actions (fetch, merge, save) in each module, assuming there could be more modules and secrets.

Would it be better to use the `outputs.tf` of each module for the secrets and store them all in one place in the `main.tf`?

Are there any better options?

Comment: This interfacing will cause issues with the secrets engine of your Vault server cluster, and will either cause unexpected behavior with Vault, or errors with the Terraform provider.

Comment: you should rethink your vault path design. Terraform expects to manage a resource exclusivly, if you create the resource in one TF module and then use another TF module to modify it you will have conflicts in your terraform that will keep undoing your changes. Instead you should store each secret into a tree structure. You can have more than one secret so use the path as a prefix. so you dont need to put everything under the one secret. Infact by design thats bad practice as then you lose the granularity of permissions for secrets.

Comment: I would also advocate moving away form vault_generic_secret and using the kv1 or kv2 vault secret resources instead to allow you better control of the resources.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty interesting problem indeed.
Probably, I would modify the approach to extract secrets in a dedicated TF-module itself. Later it can be uniformly referenced from other modules.
Here is an interesting approach on how to handle Vault secrets with TF:
https://blog.gitguardian.com/terraform-project-for-managing-vault-secrets-in-a-kubernetes-cluster/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).